# Selenium WebDriver имитация нажатия клавиш

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Есть некое поле, которое на вход принимает только цифры от 1 до 5, ввод с num-пада так же недоступен. Как сымитировать ввод с клавиатуры, если:

```
Action key2Pressed = builder.sendKeys("2").build();
```

а так же:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2)
```

Никаких результатов не дали.

Ввод пытаюсь реализовать вот для этого.
http://pdd.by/tasks/online/

Comment: Уважаемые корректоры. Я очень благодарен вам за то, что вы есть и за всю проделанную вами работу. Однако, прошу заметить, что с точки зрения орфографии слово _"сымитировать"_  является верным, а вот _"с имитировать"_ - это уже какая-то порнография.

Comment: Каких же еще коррекций ожидать от PHP-шников.

Answer (score -1):

Там как такового поля для ответа нет. Можно "слать" символы прямо в `body`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys("2")
```